# OpenShift: Unable to log in using rhc on Windows 7

Tags: git, bash, authentication, windows-7, openshift-client-tools

I am using Git Bash on Windows 7 to log into OpenShift using rhc. When I enter "rhc setup" in the console I get the following message:

> OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard
>
> This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application namespace, and check that other programs like Git are properly installed.
>
> If you have your own OpenShift server, you can specify it now. Just hit enter  to use the server for OpenShift Online: openshift.redhat.com.
> Enter the server hostname: |openshift.redhat.com|

I pressed enter without entering any hostname and I got the following message:

> You can add more servers later using 'rhc server'.
>
> Using sh***@gmail.com to login to openshift.redhat.com
> Password:

Then I typed my password and pressed enter and nothing happens. I get no further messages. I have tried it several times but the same thing happens every time. I've also tried deleting the id_rsa file from the .ssh folder but still nothing happens after entering the password. I have also checked my  password again and I am able to log in without any problems using the web-based control panel.

rhc did work fine the first time I installed it and logged in successfully, but since then I am having this problem. It has been a few days now. What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried running the rhc command in debug mode? : `rhc --debug setup`

Comment: I just did but still the same problem. Doesn't do anything after I enter the password and hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem on Windows 8. I enter the password and it hangs. The behaviour is the same no matter what I enter for the password. Previously when I entered my Openshift log in password the command continued to execute.

You can get round this problem by using adding the --token parameter to the command. To find the token, log in to Openshift, goto settings, scroll down to Authorizations and click on the latest OpenShift Console line. That will show the token value and how to use it, e.g.

rhc port-forward app --token xxxxxxxx

This is inconvenient and I would like to know how to avoid having to use the --token parameter.